# Fast Repaint Question ( Canvas Object )

Tags: java, canvas, paint, repaint

New Details:

Repaint method of my JPanel object does not work when called from inside actionPerformed event of my main class. It DOES work inside the ImageViewer method of the main class ImageViewer but does not work inide the actionPerformed method of this class.

These are the essential parts of my code which are not working properly ( repainting part ):

**Main Class:**

```
/**
 * @(#)NeatImageViewer.java
 *
 * NeatImageViewer application
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2010/11/1
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class NeatImageViewer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    GraphicsPanel gp;

    NeatImageViewer() {
               //... window components ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NeatImageViewer niv = new NeatImageViewer();
        niv.setSize(500,500);
        niv.setLocationRelativeTo(niv);
        niv.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //...
                gp = new GraphicsPanel();
                gp.img = img;
                gp.repaint(); //<!--- Not Working!
                this.add(gp);
            //...
    }

}
```

**GraphicsPanel Class:**

```
/**
 * @(#)GraphicsPanel.java
 *
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2010/11/1
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage img;

    GraphicsPanel() {
        super();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //paint method isn't executed???
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Paint!");
    }

}
```

Comment: "does not work inide the actionPerformed method of this class." means nothing to us. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swing you don't use a Canvas. You do custom painting on a JPanel or JComponent and you override the paintComponent(...) method as already stated. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, with Swing there is no need to create a custom components to show an image. You just use a JLabel with an ImageIcon. Read the section on "How to Use Icons".

Bookmark the tutorial for all the Swing basics.

Edit:

When you add a component to a visible GUI the basic code should be:

```
panel.add( ... );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I was kind of confused with Swing and AWT using them combined. However now I followed the tutorial and Im now using a JPanel  but having exactly the same pronlem: repaint does not work when called from the actionPerformed method but does work when calling it from the ImageViewer method of the main class ImageViewer. I think I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: @Skyfe, see the edit comments. You still haven't posted a SSCCE.

Comment: I updated my post with my code and which does not work (the gp.repaint() ) the way I posted it on my main post ( below EDIT2 ). 
About the add method, it can as well be left out because the paintComponent method does not actually paint anything yet but I just tried to let it be executed at all ( which didn't happen at all when using repaint method on the object ).

Comment: The size is 0, so there is nothing to paint? Last chance. WHERE IS THE SSCCE? I'm wasting my time guessing!!!!!!

Comment: Fixed it... this.validate() made it work. Somehow even the System.out.println() output of the paint method was not shown untill revalidating the frame ( sounds weird to me because I'd think it would only be the graphics ui shown that would be updated ). But anyway it's fixed now, thanks..

Comment: @Skyfe, thats what I suggested to do. Did I not say you need to revalidate() the panel you add the component to? Also, you use revalidate() in Swing, not validate(). Also, I explained why the paint() method wasn't invoked, so why are you so surprised? Why isn't the answer accepted?

Comment: I know what you used, I just told you that is not the way it is normally done. That is the way you would do it using AWT, NOT Swing. I thought you where trying to learn Swing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead of `paint(Graphics g)`.
So, the method you posted should be renamed to `paintComponent`.

**EDIT:** Have you `pack()`'ed your frame when your initialization is done?

**EDIT:** The `repaint()` method does nothing when the component isn't visible. So, you have to add it first to the JFrame, `pack()` the frame. After packing it, repainting isn't needed anymore.

Comment: I renamed the method name to paintComponent but it's still not working

Comment: When I pack the frame like: niv.pack() then I get a window with only a title and menu bar and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

(I'm Skyfe but from another IP so ain't "logged in" and couldn't comment)

I'm sorry but I don't get what's the problem???

I offered my code and it is NOT executing the paintComponent function upon calling repaint from the actionPerformed method. Just copy paste my code and compile it with a java compiler and it does NOT execute the paintComponent method upon performing an action which I can tell because I used a System.out.println() method inside the paint method. And no it does not paint anything because I'm just trying to check whether it calls the paint method AT ALL because I put a system output inside the paintComponent method which is not executed when using repaint. It was just a test and it didn't work.

So what you mean by where is the SSCCE, this is all the code I have. I compiled exactly the code I posted in my main post and the problem with it is that it does not show any system output when an action was performed ( and the repaint event was called ). I fail to see what misses in my post?

Comment: I gave you a link on how to write a SSCCE in the comment on your original question! I also provided you with a link when I answered your other question 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060006/readding-panel-to-layout-after-editing-panel. There is no reason for you not to know what a SSCCE is, you've been asked more than once. Not only that you can search the web to find out what SSCCE is!

Comment: Yes it says it's a: Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. Which my post is so I still don't get why my post would not be a "SSCCE". I posted the correct code I used, the problem and short...